# Why does my float of 999999999 become 10000000000?

Tags: c, floating-point

When I perform the following code, it has a problem:

```
float number = 999999999;
printf("%lf", number);
```

The result is `10000000000` instead of `999999999`.

Why isn't it `999999999`?

Comment: You will need bignums library of an equivalent of it , and the appropriate types.

Comment: It will be 999999999 if you use `decimal`.

Answer (score 8):

[Typical `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) can represent exactly about 2<sup>32</sup> different numbers like 1234.0 and -0.125.  `999999999` is not one of them.  `10000000000.0f` is the closest `float` alternative.

The approximation occurred during the assignment

```
float number = 999999999;  // Really assigned 10000000000.0f
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i don't know the mens about "Typical float can represent exactly about 232 different numbers like 1234.0 and -0.125. 999999999 is not one of them. ", can you show me more about it ?

Comment: @zhaoguangliang  `float` is typically 4 bytes, than is, at most,  4,294,967,296 different floating point numbers.  Yet you can code `float number = endless_different_decimal_values_in_text;`.  Sometimes code will use a number that is not representable as 1 of those 4 billion.  What do you think should happen then?