# Record field inserting 1000000000.0 instead 999999999 Flask-SQLAlchemy MySQL

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

[Table structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6RZo.png)

The column `amount` of table is type of Float datatype.

when I'm inserting a new record with the amount value 999999999 it gets automatically converted to 1000000000.0

I'm using Python3.10.2, Flask 2.2.2, Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.2, Flask-Migrate 4.0.0 and MySQL Database system

I tried both negative and positive values in negative the result is same but with negative sign

I want to insert 999999999 value as it is in the table.

Comment: Just float or float with precision? publish your column definition in full

Comment: Float is a poor choice for an amount use decimal and review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html and other stuff on float Vs decimal on web

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41366376/1048425), which in turn is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41366376/1048425) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/1048425)

Answer (score 0):

I think the data type needs to be in the right format maybe an Int64 or 32 as opposed to a float, currency or decimal type.  Note this answer: The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values. MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values .. [Why does MySQL round floats way more than expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120584/why-does-mysql-round-floats-way-more-than-expected)

Answer (score 0):

`FLOAT` datatype is an approximate numeric data value. You may experience rounding errors as it is uses four bytes for the data (`DOUBLE` uses eight bytes).

You should consider using `DECIMAL` datatype instead.

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MPvIBdyG)